# Search and delete multiple lines

Tags: search, vim

In vim

> :g/George Bush/d

deletes all lines with *George Bush.*

What if I wanted to delete ***5 lines below that start with George Bush***?

Another realistic example would be to find all DEBUG in a log4net log and delete up to the end of stack trace (which I know will be another 10 lines below it)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The :global command is your friend - learn it well.  It lets you run arbitrary :ex commands on every line that matches a regex.  It abbreviates to :g.

To delete all lines that match "George Bush":

```
:g/George Bush/ d
```

The command that follows can have its own address/range prefix, which will be relative to the matched line.  So to delete the 5th line after George Bush:

```
:g/George Bush/ .+5 d
```

To delete the DEBUG log entries:

```
:g/DEBUG/ .,+10 d
```

If you knew the stack trace was variable length but always ended at a blank line (or other regex):

```
:g/DEBUG/ .,/^$/ d
```

You can also execute a command on every line that does NOT match with :g!.  e.g. to replace "Bush" with "Obama" on every line that does not contain the word "sucks":

```
 :g!/sucks/ s/Bush/Obama/
```

The default command is to print the line to the message window.  e.g. to list every line marked TODO:

```
 :g/TODO
```

This is also useful for checking the regex matches the lines you expect before you do something destructive.

You can chain multiple commands using "|".  e.g. to change Bush to Obama AND George to Barack on every line that does not contain "sucks":

```
 :g!/sucks/ s/Bush/Obama/g | s/George/Barack/g
```

Answer (score 15):

To delete 3 lines below a pattern e.g. XXX
`:g/XXX/+d3`

To delete current line with a pattern as well as 2 more lines below
`:g/XXX/d+3`

Note: Use '-' for operations above a pattern.

Answer (score 7):

`:g/George Bush/d 6`