# sed delete multiple lines

Tags: sed, lines

I have little problem with deleting multiple lines with sed. I read a lot of guides and discussions, but none of them helped. I have a xml file, and I need to delete more occurences of these three lines:

```
<function type="class">
   <arg name="class.name">com.mycompany.name.UnLockIssueFunction</arg>
</function>
```

I wanted to use deleting just the part between `<function>`, but there is more of this tags. My xml file looks like this

```
<post-functions>
  <function type="class">
    <arg name="class.name">com.mycompany.name.function.issue.UpdateIssueStatusFunction</arg>
  </function>
  <function type="class">
    <arg name="class.name">com.mycompany.name.function.misc.CreateCommentFunction</arg>
  </function>
  <function type="class">
    <arg name="class.name">com.mycompany.name.function.issue.GenerateChangeHistoryFunction</arg>
  </function>
  <function type="class">
    <arg name="class.name">com.mycompany.name.function.issue.IssueReindexFunction</arg>
  </function>
  <function type="class">
    <arg name="class.name">com.mycompany.name.function.event.FireIssueEventFunction</arg>
    <arg name="eventTypeId">13</arg>
  </function>
  <function type="class">
    <arg name="class.name">com.mycompany.name.UnLockIssueFunction</arg>
  </function>
</post-functions>
```

Comment: You want to delete whatever tha comes between `<function type="class">` and `</function>` or including the tags too?

Comment: Do you have to do this with `sed`? It would be much better to use a scripting language with a DOM parsing library.

Comment: [Use an XML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/647772)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/<function type="class">/!b;N;N;/<function type="class">\s*\n\s*<arg name="class.name">com.mycompany.name.UnLockIssueFunction<\/arg>\s*\n\s*<\/function>/d' file
```

Comment: @Jamalissimo (You might want to accept the answer, so that potong is properly rewarded)

Answer (score 1):

When you get into fancier editing, fancier editors may help. Try reading up on scripting in VIM and take a look at these questions:

[Search and delete multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070120/search-and-delete-multiple-lines)

[VIM: globally match line, delete this and 2 following lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691605/vim-globally-match-line-delete-this-and-2-following-lines)